# Why is not WebRTC reliable for our project?

Tags: webrtc

There is a problem with our WebRTC connection in different countries:

We have used WebRTC video/voice communication successfully within the UK, but sometimes in a connection to a different country the voice from one side does not get through. For example, we have had a connection from UK to China, the person in china could see the person in the UK but could not hear him; video and voice were OK from china to the UK. Sometimes we have had successful connections between UK and china but with a specific person it does not get through at all.

In about 30% of our communications, the same thing happens. One side does not hear the other side.

Does it have anything to do with the internet in other countries?

How about ice-servers? I've read something about ice-servers. Should we implement and have our own ice server to have a reliable WebRTC connection?

Currently we are using the following public list for our servers:

```
var iceServers = {
'iceServers': [
    { url: 'stun:stun01.sipphone.com' },
    { url: 'stun:stun.ekiga.net' },
    { url: 'stun:stun.fwdnet.net' },
    { url: 'stun:stun.ideasip.com' },
    { url: 'stun:stun.iptel.org' },
    { url: 'stun:stun.rixtelecom.se' },
    { url: 'stun:stun.schlund.de' },
    { url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
    { url: 'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302' },
    { url: 'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302' },
    { url: 'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302' },
    { url: 'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302' },
    { url: 'stun:stunserver.org' },
    { url: 'stun:stun.softjoys.com' },
    { url: 'stun:stun.voiparound.com' },
    { url: 'stun:stun.voipbuster.com' },
    { url: 'stun:stun.voipstunt.com' },
    { url: 'stun:stun.voxgratia.org' },
    { url: 'stun:stun.xten.com' },
    {
        url: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
        credential: 'muazkh',
        username: 'webrtc@live.com'
    },
    {
        url: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=udp',
        credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
        username: '28224511:1379330808'
    },
    {
        url: 'turn:192.158.29.39:3478?transport=tcp',
        credential: 'JZEOEt2V3Qb0y27GRntt2u2PAYA=',
        username: '28224511:1379330808'
    }
]
};
```

Comment: Looks like you grabbed those stun/turn servers from MuazK at WebRTC Experiments. You should reduce your stun to a single public server, likely one of the google servers, and set up your own TURN server (or pay for TURN as a service). You'll be able to monitor and diagnose issues better, as well as have control. Right now, you likely don't even know which, if any, of those server credentials are valid.

Comment: @xdumaine Is it a way to solve my problem or is it just a way to diagnose and troubleshoot my problem?

Comment: First, I would implement and utilize your own NAT traversal(or subscribe to a known good one like Twilio's). Second, some networks have higher grade firewalls that will only allow connections through well known Turn servers. [Please read this for more info](https://www.iab.org/wp-content/IAB-uploads/2014/12/semi2015_reddy.pdf)